# Vector equations and possible solutions

Tags: vector-analysis

I have two set vectors **A**, **B**, **C**, **D** and **a**, **b**, **c**, **d**.

Now we know (|**A**|-|**a**|),(|**B**|-|**b**|), (|**C**|-|**c**|), and (|**D**|-|**d**|)

We know combitions of (|**A-B**|-|**a-b**|), (|**A-C**|-|**a-c**|), (|**A-D**|-|**a-d**|), (|**B-C**|-|**b-c**|), (|**B-D**|-|**b-c**|) and (|**C-D**|-|**c-d**|) as well.

And all values are equal to zero.
Is there any way to find out how many combinations of **a**, **b**, **c**, and  **d** possible. At least mathematically so that all above relations hold.

Comment: Any rotation of $\bf A, B, C, D$ would satisfy all of those relations (assuming you actually meant $\bf|B-C|-|b-c|$), and there are infinitely many rotations, unless your vector space is 1-dimensional. So there are infinitely many such sets $\bf a, b, c, d$.

Comment: yes, it was a typo...Thank you very much